# MSSQL инкремент значения

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

Как инкрементировать значение поля в БД MSSQL с использованием Linq. Вариант с прочитать-прибавить-записать не подходит ввиду одновременного инкремента разными клиентами и потоками.

По ответам из комментов, попробовал сделать вот так:

```
public static async Task IncrementDownloadCounterAsync(Int32 id)
{
    using (LICENSE_RO3Entities db = new LICENSE_RO3Entities())
    {
        using (DbContextTransaction transaction = db.Database.BeginTransaction())
        {
            DB.Update update = await db.Updates.FindAsync(id);
            if (update != null)
            {
                update.download_counter++;
            }

            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Вы LinqToSql используете или что?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, да, точнее linq to entity framework

Comment: Отлично, а что за поле инкрементировать нужно? Не ID случаем?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, нет, обычное значение типа int, скажем например счётчик скачиваний.

Comment: Вариант с использованием SQL-запроса устроит?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, я знаю будет что то типа UPDATE `table_name` SET `field` = `field` + 1, но вот не хочется отступать от Linq...

Comment: А если операции "прочитать-прибавить-записать" обернуть в транзакцию?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, подскажите как это можно сделать?

Comment: `using (var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction()) { ...; transaction.Commit(); }` - попробуйте так

Comment: @АндрейNOP, отредактировал вопрос, чтобы показать код что у меня получился, правда как проверить его работоспособность? И что будет если в using с транзакцией произойдёт исключение? Вечная блокировка таблицы на запись?

Comment: Ну, исключения, конечно же, надо обработать и в `catch` вызвать `transaction.Rollback();`

Comment: Посмотрите какой SQL фактически генерируется с транзакцией и без нее и сравните

Comment: @АндрейNOP Rollback можно не вызывать, using достаточно

Comment: @PavelMayorov, т.е. по `Dispose()` незакоммиченная транзакция автоматически откатывается? Ну а вообще на сколько такой подход верен?

Comment: Завтра на работе проверю фактический sql, спасибо за ответы)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для обновления одной записи никакая транзакция не нужна: EF умеет использовать оптимистическую блокировку для той же цели.

Если вы используете Code First - можно отметить свойство атрибутом `[ConcurrencyCheck]`. В таком случае EF при каждом обновлении записи будет дополнительно проверять что значение соответствующего атрибута в базе не изменилось.

Также можно добавить в модель свойство отмеченное атрибутом `[Timestamp]` типа `byte[]` если база данных поддерживает тип данных `rowversion` или его аналог. Отличие Timestamp от ConcurrencyCheck - в том, что ConcurrencyCheck только проверяется, а Timestamp еще и автоматически обновляется при любом изменении записи.

```
[Timestamp]
public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
```

В любом случае, какой бы из двух способов вы не выбрали - вы получите `DbUpdateConcurrencyException` если кто-то поменяет значение в базе пока вы собирались его сохранять. После этого можно будет попытаться увеличить счетчик еще раз.

---

Но самый нормальный способ - конечно же делать это средствами базы. EF не предоставляет способа делать это через Linq - поэтому надо использовать SQL-запрос:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Updates SET download_counter = download_counter + 1 WHERE Id = @p0", id);
```

Если есть желание изолировать вышележащие слои от SQL-кода - можно добавить этот запрос как метод контексту:

```
public void IncrementDownloadCounter(int id) 
{
    if (Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE Updates SET download_counter = download_counter + 1 WHERE Id = @p0", id) == 0)
    {
        throw что-нибудь;
    }
}
```